# Drawing Polyline on an ios Mapview

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

In my `Xamarin` ios app I have to draw the path as user walks,

I am planning to do this by drawing Polyline to a Map view by fetching `Lattitude & Longitude` from `CClocationManager`, But I have to deal with N number of `Lattitude & Longitude` in this case,

Is there any simple approach to do this? In our scenario We won't be knowing the destination , User will Just start a run from a point and we have to track his path on map by drawing a line, How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be to save the current last known position, which also represents you endpoint of a polyline. On a location change use it as a starting point for the next polyline. That way you draw the route with multiple polylines piece by piece.